# Send ajax data serialize to php

Tags: php, ajax, post

There is a contact form, and a submit button. (later I will try to figure out how to send that contact form data to a mail)

For now, I need to get the data to a php script....
How to forward ajax json data to a php script?
For now I just want to display via echo the contact form data that is being sent via ajax...

Here is the complete javascript function that is fired when a submit button is pressed:

```
function modalForm(){
        $('.enquiryForm form').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            change_tock();
            console.log("evo ga");
            $('.enquiryForm .status').html('');
            $('#singlePageBox .modal-footer').html('');
            var eForm = $(this),
                formData = {
                    action: eForm.attr('action'),
                    method: eForm.attr('method')
                },
            mandatoryFieldNames = 'c_phone,c_email'
            ;

            mandatoryFieldNames = $.map(mandatoryFieldNames.split(','), $.trim);
            var formFields = eForm.find('input[required], textarea[required]');
            var emptyFields = 0;
            formFields.each(function(i,v) {
                var item = $(this)
                ;
                if( !item.val() ) {
                    if( $.inArray(item.attr('name').trim() , mandatoryFieldNames) != -1 ) { 
                        item.addClass('empty_field');
                        emptyFields++;
                    }
                } else{
                    item.removeClass('empty_field');
                }
            });
            if( emptyFields !== 0) return false;
            globalDebug !== 0 && console.log(formData, eForm);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',//formData.method//,
                dataType:'json',
                url: 'slanje_poruke.php',//formData.action,
                cache: false,
                timeout: 50000,
                data: eForm.serialize()+'&sent_from='+window.location.hostname
            })
            .success(function (jqXHR, textStatus){
                $('.enquiryForm form').hide();
                $('.enquiryForm .status').append('<div class="alert alert-success">'+jqXHR.responseText+'</div>');
                $('#singlePageBox .modal-footer').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+jqXHR.responseText+'</div>');
                globalDebug !== 0 && console.log(jqXHR, textStatus);
            }).done(function (result) {
                globalDebug !== 0 && console.log(result);
            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                $('.enquiryForm .status').html('<div class="alert alert-error">Error: '+jqXHR.responseText+'</div>');
                $('#singlePageBox .modal-footer').html('<div class="alert alert-error">Error: '+jqXHR.responseText+'</div>');
                globalDebug !== 0 && console.log(jqXHR, textStatus);
            })
            ;
            return false;
        });
        return false;
    }
```

And here is the simple php slanje_poruke.php file content:

```
    <?php
    $ref = $_POST['c_ref'];
    $url = $_POST['c_url'];
    $remotepagenum = $_POST['remotePageNumber'];
    $name = $_POST['c_name'];
    $email = $_POST['c_email'];
    $phone = $_POST['c_phone'];
    $message = $_POST['c_message'];
    $sent_from = $_POST['sent_from'];



 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>console.log(' ".$email."  ');</script>";

?>
```

Now, when I press the submit button, nothing happens, only the console log message appears ('evo ga') which I set as a test when this function starts... but nothing is showing from the php file....

How do I make php script take the data sent from ajax? thank you!

Comment: Why woud you think that data would be in `$_POST['eForm']`?  You should get `$_POST[*]` where the name of each input you have in your form (plus the one additional field you are adding to query string) would take place of `*`. Just try `var_dump($_POST);` to see what is really getting posted.

Comment: now it says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'responseText' of null

Comment: I changed php file .... now when I click on submit, I get two times message written in console.log  and an error message under submit button...

Comment: That likely because you are not returning valid JSON with the `var_dump()`. Don;t woory about that problem now- just trying to solve getting data in PHP. You should be able to at least see the result in the response content within your developer tools.

Comment: I changed the php file as you may see... now I get a content of email input text... but it is printed twice ... how do I say to ajax that php finish successfully so there is no error message?

Comment: OK looking at your revised post, it seems you are handling different post field more appropriately.  Rather than sending back invalid response (your ajax is expecting JSON)/ Why dont you do `echo json_encode($_POST);` so you can better see the posted data back on the client side. Don't echo out javascript.  Your PHP is getting the data if you are able to populate `$email` in PHP.  Not sure what your question is now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77259/discussion-between-volkan-and-mike-brant).

Answer (score 0):

To grab the form contents, serialize it using jQuery [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)() method. This transforms the form content into a query string, which you can simply submit the data as it and $_POST will contain all your form data.